# Tomcat 7.0 Out Of Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Windoes Server

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, out-of-memory

I am using Tomcat 7.0 And Windows Server OS 2008.
I am trying to upload 30 MB File when i try to read file then following error is generating.

I have 6 GB RAM and out of 6GB 2GB is free.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:41)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:458)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1015)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:312)
    at net.coobird.thumbnailator.util.BufferedImages.copy(Unknown Source)
    at net.coobird.thumbnailator.tasks.io.OutputStreamImageSink.write(Unknown Source)
    at net.coobird.thumbnailator.tasks.SourceSinkThumbnailTask.write(Unknown Source)
    at net.coobird.thumbnailator.Thumbnailator.createThumbnail(Unknown Source)
    at net.coobird.thumbnailator.Thumbnails$Builder.toOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.toocoolproductions.model.service.impl.UserSettingsServiceImpl.getScaledImage(UserSettingsServiceImpl.java:332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

**setavn.bat**

```
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%/jre1.6.0_20/win" (
    if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
        set JAVA_HOME=
    )

    set "JRE_HOME=%CATALINA_HOME%/jre1.6.0_20/win"
)

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx1024m -Xms1024M  -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
echo %JAVA_OPTS%;
```

I try a lot after chages settings for -Xmx1024m -Xms1024M  -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m for changes different-diffrent sizes but those are not working for me.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You don't have 6 GB for tomcat. You only have 1 GB allotted for Tomcat. Even then 30 Mb shouldn't bring the server down. You said you tried to upload the file and while reading it, the error was thrown. Are you sure the upload is successful? You're doing a `BufferedImages.copy`. do you have other images in that class? Can you get a heap dump on error? If you are using Oracle JDK, try these setting `-XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid<pid>.hprof and -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError `

Comment: yes file upload successfully. when i try to generate Thubnails from it at that this error is generating. Let me try to generate Dump file as as you say.

Comment: what happen if i set .hprof file? what is use of this configuration?

Comment: It seems you're using this https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/ library. Can you put what follows at line 331 of UserSettingsServiceImpl.java? Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("HEAP Usage [Mb]:"+ (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / (1024*1024));

Comment: Besides, in your case (heap), the only relevant settings are -Xmx and -Xms. You can try to use -Xmx2G - Xms1G.

Comment: I try for -Xmx2G - Xms1G but i am not able to start my tomcat.

Comment: System.out.println("HEAP Usage [Mb]:"+ (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / (1024*1024)); This code is returning me between 500 to 700

Comment: Keep the Xms to a low value. May be 512. You don't want Tomcat to start with all the memory is allowed to have. Xmx is max heap and Xms is the one it starts up with.

Comment: It try  Xms to 512Mb but now it is return 400 to 600 but return same error. :|

Comment: Simply dont read the whole file into memory. Just stream the file from disk over the network into a buffered reader and write it to the servers disk in the same step.

Comment: I am running two tomcat on my server. Is there any chance problem because of this?

Answer (score 0):

### referer official issue:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when resize a specific image.
https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/issues/147
https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/wiki/Changes#outofmemoryerror-workaround
https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/issues/69
```

### solution:

https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/wiki/Changes#outofmemoryerror-workaround

```
System.setProperty("thumbnailator.conserveMemoryWorkaround", "true");
```